The navbar doesn't want to be on the left side
I tried making a Navbar where the menu items should be on the right and the logo on the left. But it seems impossible. No matter what I try, the elements don't move in the direction that I want. What's wrong with my code? Can someone please help me?
I make it with float: right that doesn't work.
If I try to fix it with "display: flex", the items stay on the bottom of the header. The same applies for the logo. The Logo should be more on the right side, but it doesn't want to move.
Is there something wrong with my HTML?


:root {
  --background: #D9E4EF;
  --header: #62ABF5;
  --header2: #1062B3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background);
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 10%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: var(--header);
}

.menu-nav {
  color: var(--background);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-nav_item {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover {
  color: var(--header2);
}

.logo {
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0;
}
<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="meb_logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu-nav">
        <li class="menu-nav_item active">
          <a href="index.html" class="menu-nav_link">
        Home
    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav_item">
          <a href="about.html" class="menu-nav_link">
        Duyurlar
    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav_item">
          <a href="projects.html" class="menu-nav_link">
        Projeler
    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-nav_item">
          <a href="contacts.html" class="menu-nav_link">
        Iletisim
    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </span>
    </div>
  </header>
  </body>




Please [edit] the question and adjust the snippet to create a [mre]. The HTML currently posted is invalid

just use flex on header
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;

here is the code


 :root {
            --background: #D9E4EF;
            --header: #62ABF5;
            --header2: #1062B3;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: "Arimo", sans-serif;
        }

        body {
            background-color: var(--background);
            height: 100vh;
        }

        header {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 20px 10%;
            z-index: 100;
            background: var(--header);
            /*new code*/
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            /*new code end*/
        }

        .menu-nav {
            color: var(--background);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: end;
            align-items: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .menu-nav_item {
            text-decoration: none;
            margin-left: 35px;
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li:hover {
            color: var(--header2);
        }

        .logo {
            width: 70px;
            margin: 0;
        }
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="meb_logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
        </div>
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="menu-nav">
                <li class="menu-nav_item active">
                    <a href="index.html" class="menu-nav_link">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-nav_item">
                    <a href="about.html" class="menu-nav_link">
                        Duyurlar
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-nav_item">
                    <a href="projects.html" class="menu-nav_link">
                        Projeler
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-nav_item">
                    <a href="contacts.html" class="menu-nav_link">
                        Iletisim
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </span>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>



